# install program without ./configure file in debian

Tags: installation, debian

This is probably a dumb question but I don't know how/where to put the files for Blender. From the repositories the only version available is 2.63 but I want 2.69 of Blender. Downloading the files straight from blender.org gives me a runnable program, but how do I place it on the machine as if it were install through the repositories via apt-get?

Such as shortcuts and everything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use alacarte (if you don't have it, use apt-get) to customize menus... to add a new application with icons and stuff like you said, open alacarte, select the menu you want to add blender, click on "New Item" and a new window will pop. There, give a name to the new item, put the path for the blender runnable program, and select the icon image by clicking on the generic launcher image and that's it! Blender is now on your search :)